# A ClassFormatError using StrutsTestCase on NetBeans6.9

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, struts, netbeans-6.9

I'm trying to use StrutsTestCase to do unit test on my java application using Struts 1.3.8 framework. However, it's quite upset that when I write a test class and try to run it, here comes an error. The error information is given below.

I'm quite confused for when I open the class HttpServletRequestWrapper, there's a red line below the construction method. I use Java-EE-glassfish-v3 as the lib, and when I changed it to Java EE 6 the condition is still the same.

I use Struts 1.3.8 and StrutsTestCase 2.1.4, and my IDE is NetBeans 6.9 and the operating system is Fedora 14 (The Java jdk is OpenJDK). I failed to figure out why this error happens. I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me any help.

Here's the error msg in NetBeans:

> Absent Code attribute in method that
>   is not native or abstract in class
>   file
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper
>   java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent
>   Code attribute in method that is not
>   native or abstract in class file
>   javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
>
> ```
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
> ```

My thanks.

Comment: pls post your test file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your main function?
You may try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    junit.textui.TestRunner.run(LoginActionTest.class);
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, but the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a version mismatch.app j2ee version and the version for which struts lib is written should be same.

Comment: I thought so before. But the Struts 1.3.8 framework and J2EE library used are all default libs in NetBeans 6.9. And everything except the unit test using StrutsTestCase  is okay now. The servlet version is 2.4 and my StrutsTestCase is exactly the version that supports it. This all makes me quite confusing.